# Is it possible to explain how to use LaTeX in questions / answers in the "How to format" help box?

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

After a bit of time using the site I can see people using lots of nice equations. But there's nothing in the "How to format" help box (or in the "full reference >>" link) saying how to do this.

I got a couple of comments like "use $$ around your equations" but that didn't actually work. I guess I had the format slightly off or something. I've not used LaTeX before either so didn't naturally know what to do.

I think it would be a great help (especially for newbies) to have a single line in the "How to format" section saying something like "Enter formulas like this '$$ \pi $$' - see  for details of how to do this better" with a link to a LaTeX reference.

I think the current feature isn't very 'discoverable' unless you already know about it.

Comment: Agreed, it took a long long time for me to find it in meta-SO!

Comment: @Sklivvz That is too common, I'm sorry to say. This isn't the only problem suffering from the lack of adaptation to the needs on the sites. There are other basic questions that you have to go search on Meta.SO for, and then probably sort through various related questions that may not be what you are looking for. (I was thinking about one earlier that vexed me a little, maybe I will remember what it was.)

Comment: More on LaTeX: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/136/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/804/2451 , http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11127 , http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68388 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic Something horrible has happened to the formatting of this question...

Answer (score 4):

It is already posted on Meta.SO by KennyTM, so all we can do is wait (or upvote the post on meta): [There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it)